# Onsubmit of a form, open up on a new tab

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browser, ruby-on-rails-2

On selection of batch. I render a partial(displays students), after selection of students, I should generate a pdf in a new tab.

**_batch_students.html.erb**

```
<% form_for :custom_reports, :url=>{:action=>"custom_report_pdf"} do |f| %>
#code
<%= f.submit "► #{t('pdf_report')}", :class=>"submit-button"%>
```

It currently works fine, but how to get the pdf in new tab? Need to use Javascript?

And the `url` currently with pdf looks like

> `http://localhost:3000/design_custom_reports/custom_report_pdf`

On reload in `chrome` alerts me to `resend data` but in `firefox` it doesn't prompt and results in `error`.

*Rails 2, Ubuntu 12.04*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute [`target="_blank"`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) on the html form:

```
<% form_for :custom_reports, :url=>{:action=>"custom_report_pdf"}, :html => {:target => '_blank'} do |f| %>
```

It will generate the following HTML

```
<form target="_blank" ... >
```